# why does the yubico openID not work with stackoverflow?

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow, openid

Why does the Stackoverflow openid association not allow the [Yubico OpenId](http://openid.yubico.com) to be associated?

Stackoverflow returns this message..

*Unable to log in with your OpenID provider:
failed to authenticate, returning Failed. Please ensure your identifier is correct and try again.*

Comment: Email the team in the "contact us" link to have them sort you out.

Comment: what does that even mean?

Comment: You might want to accept [an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/44284/146482)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yubico fixed this on their end:

> Hey, it looks like Yubico fixed the problem on their end already.  I just logged in with my Yubikey to SO and it worked great.

That's from Andrew Arnott, the primary author of DotNetOpenAuth.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but i Just tried it 2/3/10 and it didn't work

from yubico's website

> Yubico OpenID Server
>
> ```
> Welcome!
>
> There are two ways to use the Yubico OpenID server. The simplest is
> ```
>
> to go to any site which supports
>   OpenID and log in to it using the
>   following OpenID URL:
>
> ```
> http://openid.yubico.com/server.php/idpage?user=cccccccbihth
>
> You will then be redirected to our OpenID server, and can login to the
> ```
>
> site authenticated using your YubiKey.
>
> ```
> If you wish to use a more personal OpenID URL, you need to set up your
> ```
>
> own web site and be able to modify the
>   HTML code for it. Insert the following
>   markup into the  of the HTML
>   document at your own home page:
>
> ```
> <link rel="openid.server" href="http://openid.yubico.com/server.php" />
> <link rel="openid.delegate" href="http://openid.yubico.com/server.php/idpage?user=cccccccbihth"
> ```
>
> />
>
> ```
> Once you have made this change, you should be able to use your own URL
> ```
>
> as the OpenID URL when using any
>   OpenID enabled site.
>
> ```
> You can verify that it is working by using the external OpenID Checkup
> ```
>
> tool.
>
> ```
> You can read more about OpenID.
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I use http://www.clavid.com/, which can use Yubikey for authentication. Not really a solution, but it is a workaround.

Comment: clavid.com has shutdown being an free OIDC provider so it is now long an option to login to stackexchange sites.

Answer (score 0):

Just got word back from yubico forums

they upgraded there OID server I just tested and it worked

this can be closed